# Path to TEMP-Folder won't change

Tags: windows, windows-10, environment-variables, temporary-files

I have changed the path of my *TEMP*-Folder to *D:\TEMP* by setting the environment-variables *TEMP* and *TMP* accordingly (using the UI under System->Advanced Options -> Environment Variables). However, if I type *%TEMP%* into the Windows search field, I still get to the old path. Did it change correctly or have I done something wrong?

Comment: How, exactly, did you set the environment variables? Please [edit] your question and include this essential information.

Comment: Did you change both the "System" and "User" TEMP variables?

Comment: Yes I did change both.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I figured that it had changed correctly. Because when I deleted the file remnants left in the old path, I noticed all the files got deleted without getting the "file in use" warning and the folder remained empty meaning no temporary files were being created there any more.